# How to send AJAX request from a <form> created by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a jQuery textarea from where I am posting form values with a button. I don't want to refresh the page and use AJAX for this purpose so that the page does not get refreshed. I have tried a lot but the solution does not seem to be coming out. Here is my code for the same. Any insight will be really helpful.

Here is my code,

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.click_notes').on('click',function(){
 var tid = $(this).data('question-id'); 
$(this).closest('ul').find('.demo').html("<div class='comment_form'><span onclick='$(this).parent().hide()'><b>X</b></span><form id = 'contactForm1' action='submit.php' method='post'><textarea required cols ='50' class='span10' name='notes' rows='6'></textarea><br><input class='btn btn-primary' id = 'submitnotes' name= 'submit_notes' type='submit' onclick = 'submitform()' value='Add Notes'><input type='hidden' name='submitValue' value='"+tid+"' /></form><br></div>");
 });
});

</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

      function submitform() {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Submission was successful.');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('An error occurred.');
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
        }

</script>
```

Comment: `e` is undefined

Comment: _the solution does not seem to be coming out_ Please in future describe what the problem actually is

Comment: `1.6.1` — This is an ancient version of jQuery with known security issues. Upgrade to the current version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this hook to the `submit` event of the `form` itself, not the `click` event of the submit button. Also note that you shouldn't be using `on*` event attributes. As the HTML content of the form is dynamically appended to the DOM you can use a delegated event handler on both the `form` and `span` instead. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.click_notes').on('click', function() {
    var tid = $(this).data('question-id');
    $(this).closest('ul').find('.demo').html('<div class="comment_form"><span><b>X</b></span><form id="contactForm1" action="submit.php" method="post"><textarea required cols="50" class="span10" name="notes" rows="6"></textarea><br><input class="btn btn-primary" id="submitnotes" name="submit_notes" type="submit" value="Add Notes"><input type="hidden" name="submitValue" value="' + tid + '" /></form><br></div>');
  });

  $(document).on('submit', '#contactForm1', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: this.method,
      url: this.action,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('Submission was successful.');
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        console.log('An error occurred.');
        console.log(xhr);
      },
    });
  }).on('click', 'span', function() {
    $(this).parent().hide()
  });
});
```

Also note that you're including two versions of jQuery, one of which (1.6.1) is getting nearly 8 years out of date. I'd suggest using a single reference to jQuery 3.3.1 instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. I appreciate . But the prob remains same. I mean still on clicking the submit button, the URL changes and page redirects to submit.php. Is there something else that is missing

Comment: Apologies - there was a couple of typos in the answer. I've updated it for you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks alot mate. I appreciate your effort. One question, how can I display a message that the submission is done successfully and close the textarea.

Comment: Currently when I am trying to display message it loops through the loop and displays on every item present on the page. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: You could use an `alert()` to show the message and `$(this).closest('.comment_form').remove()` to get rid of the form.